# Django AJAX: Access data from Dynamic multiple forms

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms

Each form's input is associated with a unique data-comment-pk. I'm trying to access the value of data-comment-pk of the input which is submitted. Currently, the AJAX success function's `alert(comment_pk)` is only fetching me the comment_pk of the first form. How can I access the `comment_pk` of the form which is submitted instead of getting the `comment_pk` of the first form?
html template

```
{% for comment in object_list %}
<h3>{{comment.comment}} by {{comment.username}}</h3>
<form class="score-form">
    <input type="submit" value="Up" name="up" class="Up" data-comment-pk="{{comment.pk}}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Down" name="down" />
</form>
{% endfor %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".score-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var comment_pk = $(".Up").attr("data-comment-pk");
        var url = comment_pk + "/vote";
        console.log(url)
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: { "up": 'UP' },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response["valid"]) {
                    alert(comment_pk);
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

models.py

```
class CommentModel(VoteModel, models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
class CommentView(ListView):
  model = CommentModel
def comment_vote(request, comment_id):
  if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
    # do some stuff
    return JsonResponse({"valid": True}, status=200)
```

Comment: use ```$(this)``` on your selector to select the current HTML element. I think this should solve the problem.

Comment: @iliya Hey. Did you mean exactly like the ans posted below? Sorry, JS isn't exactly my strong point

Comment: yes, but with a little difference in syntax. Try this instead ```var comment_pk = $(".Up", this ).attr("data-comment-pk");```.

Comment: @iliya THANK YOU SO MUCH. Jesus Christ, that worked. I'm crying haha. Wasted almost an entire day today, Thank you, again :)

Comment: you are welcome. If it helped cast a vote, for other it maybe helpful :)

Comment: @iliya Yes. You haven't written an answer tho. Write the ans so that I can mark it as solution

Comment: here you are :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to this problem :

```
var comment_pk = $(".Up", this ).attr("data-comment-pk");
```

Using `this` will return the current `HTML` element.

Answer (score 0):

**try:** add "this" to before .Up in the comment_pk.
let me know if it works.
this- will get the currect form that have been submit and get the .Up Class

```
<script>
    $(".score-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var comment_pk = $("this .Up").attr("data-comment-pk");
        var url = comment_pk + "/vote";
        console.log(url)
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: { "up": 'UP' },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response["valid"]) {
                    alert(comment_pk);
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        })
    })
 </script>
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your reply. But that didn't help. In fact, now while console logging, I'm getting ```undefined```.